# After Ajax request session is expired in php

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, rest

I have created REST API in codeigniter. This API I am using on my codeigniter website and It's working fine. I have created one JavaScript for call API using ajax. It's also working fine but problem is that after calling ajax If refresh the page or tired to open another page of website it's send to me login page. I don't know why my session is expired ?

I have check in chrome developer tools. After calling ajax clicked page return 302 status.

```
$.ajax({
            url: rest_url,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(data){                  
                //some code
            }
        });
```

Comment: What is the version of your codeigniter?

Comment: Client version means website version is 2.0 and API version is 3.0

Comment: I want to know if you use codeigniter 2 or codeigniter3

Comment: I am using codeigniter 2

Comment: This is working fine in my development machine Linux. But I am facing this  problem on server

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by session ID regeneration during AJAX requests
If you upgrade your codeigniter , it will be good because we have fixed this error with codeigniter. If you can't , you can get a view in how we have fixed it here [Fix of this bug in github](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/commit/3ce60fcfd0c4f9e85d483beeee732eb181e6f4f0). As you can see you just need to change the if condition on this file system/libraries/Session.php.  I think that my answer will be usefull for you.

[image]

Comment: This is working fine in my development machine Linux. But I am facing this  problem on server

Comment: Take a look if the file has really changed on your server and then test it again

Comment: As I told it's working fine on development machine. This problem will occur when upload on server.